# Counting the number of times the first word in a line appears when read from file with exceptions

Tags: python, string, file, dictionary, count

Using a dummy file (streamt.txt) with the following contents:

```
andrew I hate mondays.
fred Python is cool.
fred Ko Ko Bop Ko Ko Bop Ko Ko Bop for ever
andrew @fred no it isn't, what do you think @john???
judy @fred enough with the k-pop
judy RT @fred Python is cool.
andrew RT @judy @fred enough with the k pop
george RT @fred Python is cool.
andrew DM @john Oops
john DM @andrew Who are you go away! Do you know him, @judy?
```

The first word of each line represents a user and the rest of the line is a message, similar to twitter. I need to print a list of the top *n* (entered by user) original posting users (most messages) next to the number of messages they sent.

This doesn't include any message with 'RT' at the start. Formatted in justified columns in lexicographic order in the case of ties.

As it stands, my code only finds the most used words in the messages and it doesn't exclude RT and DM messages or account for n:

```
file=open('streamt.txt')

counts=dict()
for line in file:
    words=line.split()
    for word in words:
    counts[word]=counts.get(word, 0)+1

lst=list()
for key,value in counts.items():
    new=(value, key)
    lst.append(new)

lst=sorted (lst, reverse=True)

for value, key in lst[:10]:
    print(value,key)
```

This is my output:

```
6 Ko
5 @fred
4 andrew
3 you
3 is
3 cool.
3 RT
3 Python
3 Bop
2 with
```

The actual output should be:

```
Enter n: 10
3 andrew
2 fred
1 john judy
```

Any ideas as to how I should do this?

Comment: Is your text file consistent with your actual output ? Shouldn't **andrew** be 2 per your instructions ?

Comment: Yeah I noticed that earlier. That is the output solution I was given, but I imagine it should actually be 2

Comment: The output solution you were given ? It appears that you are not even checking if the output is matching with the instructions.

Comment: Turns out it was only RT that needed to be excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from pathlib import Path

def main():
    n = input('Enter n: ')
    try:
        n = int(n)
    except:
        print('Invalid input.')
        return
    ss = Path('streamt.txt').read_text().strip().split('\n')
    c = Counter([
        i.strip().split(' ', 1)[0] for i in ss
        if i.strip().split(' ', 2)[1] not in ('RT',)
    ])
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in c.most_common():
        d[v].append(k)
    print('\n'.join([f'{k} {" ".join(v)}' for k, v in list(d.items())[:n]]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Enter n: 10
3 andrew
2 fred
1 judy john
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) :

```
from collections import Counter

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if 'DM' not in line and 'RT' not in line:
            words = line.split()
            lst.append(words[0])

for k, v in Counter(lst).items():
    print(v, k)

# 2 andrew
# 2 fred                                                     
# 1 judy
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **collections** Module.

**Demo:**

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if 'RT' not in line and 'DM' not in line:
            d[line.strip().split()[0]] += 1

d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
for k,v in d:
    print(v, k)
```

**Output:**

```
2 andrew
2 fred
1 judy
```

Comment: It gives the correct answer but it isn't formatted correctly

Comment: `for k,v in d.items():
    print(v, k)` ?

Comment: Any idea how to have ties next to one another and for it to be printed descending order?

Comment: Updated snippet.

Comment: where would you place the n variable in this?

Comment: `for k,v in d[:n]:
    print v, k`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete solution using only `defaultdict` as imported class. Note that it takes into account the fact that several users may have the same number of messages:

```
from collections import defaultdict

n = int(input("Enter n: "))

# Build dictionary with key = name / value = number of messages
d = defaultdict(int)
with open('file.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
        words = line.split()
        if words[1] not in ["RT"]:
            d[words[0]] += 1

# Build dictionary with key = number of messages / value = list of names
d_new = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in d.items():
    d_new[v].append(k)

# Keep only the top n items in dictionary sorted by number of messages
listOfNbAndNames = sorted(d_new.items(), reverse = True)[:n]
for nb,names in listOfNbAndNames:
    print(nb, " ".join(names))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done efficiently by recovering username of an author with `str.split` and keeping count with `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter

with open('streamt.txt', 'r') as file:
    count = Counter(line.split()[0] for line in file)

print(count) # Counter({'andrew': 4, 'fred': 2, 'judy': 2, 'george': 1, 'john': 1})
```

If you want the users sorted by number of message, your can then use `Counter.most_common`. You optionally pass as argument the number of items you want returned.

```
print(count.most_common())
# prints:  [('andrew', 4), ('fred', 2), ('judy', 2), ('george', 1), ('john', 1)]

print(count.most_common(2))
# prints:  [('andrew', 4), ('fred', 2)]
```