# Excluding lines from a text file (Python)

Tags: python

I recently posted about trying to get my code to exclude the words "RT" and "DM" when counting lines. What I am trying to achieve with this program is to read a number x from the user and then output that amount of users as the top x "tweeters". The tweets from users that include DM or RT shouldn't be counted however they still are being counted with this code. I have made changes to the first lines of my code however I believe the reason it is not giving the right output is because of something in the rest of the full code:

```
x = input("Enter a number: ")
with open('stream.txt', 'r') as file:
    fileread = file.readlines()

tweets = [string.split() for string in fileread
          if not "DM" in string and not "RT" in string]
numofwords = [len(word)-1 for word in tweets]
with open('stream.txt',"r") as f:
    wordlist = [r.split()[0] for r in f]
maximum = max(numofwords)
users = [a for a, b in enumerate(wordlist) if b == maximum]
tweetuser = [word[0] for word in [tweets[a] for a in users]]
tweetuser.sort()


word_counter = {}
for word in wordlist:
    if word in word_counter:
        word_counter[word] += 1
    else:
        word_counter[word] = 1

popular_words = sorted(word_counter, key = word_counter.get, reverse = 
True)
top = popular_words[:x]
top.sort()
for user in top:
    print(user)
```

Here is the text file I have been using:

```
 andrew I hate mondays.
 fred Python is cool.
 fred Ko Ko Bop Ko Ko Bop Ko Ko Bop for ever
 andrew @fred no it isn't, what do you think @john???
 judy @fred enough with the k-pop
 judy RT @fred Python is cool.
 andrew RT @judy @fred enough with the k pop
 george RT @fred Python is cool.
 andrew DM @john Oops
 john DM @andrew Who are you go away! Do you know him, @judy?
 sam DM
 sam DM
 sam DM
 sam DM
```

The output I get with the number input of 3 (top 3 users) is:

```
andrew
fred
sam
```

This is incorrect because sam was a decoy user I included who should not appear in any list as all his tweets include the word DM. All help is greatly appreciated thank you :)

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Counting the number of times the first word in a line appears when read from file with exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50502148/counting-the-number-of-times-the-first-word-in-a-line-appears-when-read-from-fil)

Comment: yes I'm sorry that person does have the same assignment and I didnt know that person already posted about this. I just want to know what small adjustments I need to make in my own code to learn instead of copying and pasting a whole new program from the other thread. sorry :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
wordlist = [r.split()[0] for r in f]
```

to

```
wordlist = [r.split()[0] for r in f if "DM" not in r and "RT" not in r]
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you are doing it to complicated maybe. If you just want the top x users you could do:

```
x = input("top x users: ")
users = []
with open("stream.txt","r") as sin:
    for line in sin:
        words = line.split()
        if not "DM" in words and not "RT" in words and not words[0] in users:
            users.append(words[0])

print(users)
```

that outputs ['andrew', 'fred', 'judy'] for me.