# Counting strings from multiple files (Newsfeed Activity)

Tags: python, string, file, dictionary, count

My program is meant to print the top *n* users that have seen the most 'tweets' and how many they would have seen. A seen tweet is defined as a tweet that comes from a user they follow, when they are mentioned (@user) in a tweet, a DM, or as the author of retweeted tweets.

Using a dummy file (follows.txt):

```
andrew fred
fred
judy andrew fred
george judy andrew
john george
```

The first word being a user with the remaining words in the string being people they follow

A snippet of code used to determine who each user follows:

```
for line in lines:
    names = line.split()
    follow_dict[names[0]] = len(names)-1
    if max_follower < len(names)-1:
        max_follower = len(names)-1
```

Using a second dummy file (stream.txt) the general activity is shown:

```
andrew I hate mondays.
fred Python is cool.
fred Ko Ko Bop Ko Ko Bop Ko Ko Bop for ever
andrew @fred no it isn't, what do you think @john???
judy @fred enough with the k-pop
judy RT @fred Python is cool.
andrew RT @judy @fred enough with the k pop
george RT @fred Python is cool.
andrew DM @john Oops
john DM @andrew Who are you go away! Do you know him, @judy?
```

The sample out put of the code is supposed to be:

```
Enter n: 10
6 judy
5 fred george
3 andrew john
```

Usually if I were to ask for help here I would at least have some code to show that works, but not completely as intended or with errors. This time I don't even know where to begin. If there is anyone that can help me I'd be very grateful.

Comment: please mark this as duplicate. the same homework has been posted as question at least 3 times the last few days. make proper search here and you will get your answers. for example here: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510662/excluding-lines-from-a-text-file-python/50510910#50510910)

Comment: It is a different question to the ones posted before, there are a number of questions related to the same project.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can solve it that way (going from each user and count the tweets they see), but it's way too inefficient (that can't be how twitter do it). here's another way:

1. make a reversed dict of followers: for each user who follows her
2. the same dict can store the count of tweets seen by each user
3. for each tweet, update the count